# Mongoose returning NULL on findOneAndUpdate()

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

To learn the MEAN stack (using Mongoose), I'm creating a StackOverflow type application. I have Questions that are stored in Mongo(v3.0.7) and they have Answer sub-documents.

I am trying to increment the Vote of an Answer, but when the question is returned it is null. I'm pretty sure there's something wrong with the query, specifically where I'm trying to get the answer with the ID I need to modify.

Question Schema:

```
var questionsSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  answers: [ answerSchema ],
  });
```

Answer Schema:

```
var answerSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  votes: { type: Number, default: 0 },
  });
```

Querying for _id returns null:

```
Question.findOneAndUpdate(
  {_id: req.params.questionId, 'answers._id': req.params.answerId },
  { $inc: { 'answers.$.votes': 1 } },
  { new: true },
  function(err, question){
    if (err) { return next(err); }
    //question is returned as NULL
    res.json(question);
  });
```

Querying for 0 votes works:

```
Question.findOneAndUpdate(
  {_id: req.params.questionId, 'answers.votes': 0 },
  { $inc: { 'answers.$.votes': 1 } },
  { new: true },
  function(err, question){
    if (err) { return next(err); }
    //question is returned as NULL
    res.json(question);
  });
```

UPDATE:
Query through Mongo the result is returned:

```
db.questions.find({_id: ObjectId('562e635b9f4d61ec1e0ed953'), 'answers._id': ObjectId('562e63719f4d61ec1e0ed954') })
```

BUT, through Mongoose, NULL is returned:

```
 Question.find(
{_id: Schema.ObjectId('562e635b9f4d61ec1e0ed953'), 'answers._id': Schema.ObjectId('562e63719f4d61ec1e0ed954') },
```

Comment: Have you tried `'answers._id': ObjectId(req.params.answerId)` or `'answers._id': new ObjectId(req.params.answerId)` or anything like that? Also, what about in MongoDB CLI, does it come back with something?

Comment: Just updated: Good idea on the CLI, that does return the document, but when I add ObjectID through Mongoose, null is still returned.

Comment: Yes, like I was saying you'll probably need `new ObjectId()` and declare it at the top of your file. It's silly, I'm still not positive why this even needs to be done...

Comment: @mcpDESIGNS I think I was calling Schema.ObjectId, where I should have been calling mongoose.Types.ObjectId... so yea, sounds like you had it. Thx!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use mongoose Types ObjectID

http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#types-objectid-js:

```
var ObjectId = mongoose.Types.ObjectId;
Question.find({
    _id: '562e635b9f4d61ec1e0ed953',
   'answers._id': new ObjectId('562e63719f4d61ec1e0ed954')
})
```

Final answer to the original update question:

```
Question.findOneAndUpdate(
   {_id: req.params.questionId, 
    'answers._id': new ObjectId(req.params.answerId) },
   { $inc: { 'answers.$.votes': 1 } },
   { new: true },
   function(err, question){
     if (err) { return next(err); }
     res.json(question);
   });
```

Comment: This was the closest answer, but needed modification. You can't new up the ObjectId until you use it.

Comment: Yeah, it is true, but why do use suggest to use new ObjectId just in one place in your edit (in 'answers._id' part)?

Question.find({
    _id: '562e635b9f4d61ec1e0ed953',
   'answers._id': new ObjectId('562e63719f4d61ec1e0ed954')
}). And I don't see a point of using 2 queries here, so replacing find() with findOne({_id: "562e635b9f4d61ec1e0ed953"}) should be the best options here IMHO

Comment: You can use it in bot, but from my testing its not required. Not sure how it works under the covers, but they probably know that '_id' is an ObjectId and do the cast, but maybe they don't know that 'answers._id' is an ObjectId.... no idea, but that code sample returns exactly what I was looking for, so thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You don't need `ObjectId` at all:

```
Question.findOne({_id: "562e635b9f4d61ec1e0ed953"}, callback)
```

Mongoose handles the string for you.

In addition, using `find()` and querying by `_id` will result in an array of length 0 or 1. Using `findOne()` will return the document object.